# scrolling in a ScrollableControl: is there a .NET variant of MFC ViewPort?

Tags: c#, draw

I'm learning how to draw in Winforms. I've created a Form, with a panel with scrollbars. Upone Event Paint I draw an ellipse. This is fairly straightforward:

```
this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;
this.panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 300);

private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle ellipse = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, new Size(400, 400));
    ellipse.Offset(this.panel1.AutoScrollPosition);
    using (Pen myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, ellipse);
    }
}

private void OnPanelScroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    this.panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

This works fine, but the complete image is redrawn when resizing or scrolling the panel.

A long time ago, in the time of MFC there was the notion of ViewPort / SetViewPortOrg / mapping modes / etc.. Scrolling and resizing did not require a recalculation of the complete image. Once you had drawn the image you didn't have to redraw as long as the complete image was not changed. All you had to do was move the viewport, or change the mapping mode

Does .NET have something similar that can do the scrolling for me? Maybe I should not draw on a panel, but on another subclass of a ScrollableControl?